# Clash between thermodynamic and kinetic processes

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics, reaction-control

I have often come across reactions where kinetic and thermodynamic processes give completely different outputs. I was told that in such cases check temperature, if temperature controlled, then take thermodynamic product otherwise if reaction is very fast (not temperature controlled) then consider the kinetic product.

I was also told that if there is a case where you can't decide whether it is temperature controlled or speed controlled, then always take the thermodynamic product.

My question is: Why will thermodynamic processes have an upper hand in the latter case?
CH2CHC(CH2)CH3 what MAJOR product does it produce on giving 1 equivalent HBr?

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: An example from organic chemistry.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.  Is it something like:  what is the difference between solving a problem using the equilibrium constant and using the reaction kinetics equations?

Comment: Not quite. Look at the example that I gave. If we assume CH2CHC(CH2)CH3 to follow temperature controlled reaction when provided with 1 equivalent of HBr, the product it gives (I think) will be different from the one if we assume the reaction to be very fast and not quite affected by temperature.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that there is a sequence of reactions occurring, and the rate constants for these reactions vary differently as functions of temperature.  Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Quite true. I will explain. We know that the rate constant of a reaction is a function of temperature . So naturally If temperature changes then the reaction path might also change(considering various factors like activation energy etc..).  i.e. Of heat is supplied then it may take a part with a higher activation energy. However if the reaction is super fast, i.e. much much less compared to the minimum time required to reach a path with a higher activation energy, then the reaction might not get the time to reach another higher activation energy path, even when supplied with energy.

Comment: So now as my question stands, while writing reactions, we always do not know the time in which the reaction occurs. So I was told that for almost all cases, if such controversial situations rise, take the thermodynamic product to be the major one. Why?

Comment: My understanding is that you have several reactions occurring simultaneously, and they all have different activation energies.  Maybe the activation energies for undesirable by-products are high, so you want to keep the temperature as low as possible.  But there are also time constraints related to the economics of the process.  So you might want higher temperature to have higher reaction rates and lower the size of the equipment.  Is that correct?  Also, please define the thermodynamic product.  It this what you end up with at equilibrium?

Comment: Sir, I am a Student, who is being given Equations to write down in an exam I am not Experimenting things in industry. The equation I gave as an example was an organic reaction given to me to write down the major product. What I had thought was that in the equation above, if I considered it to be slow enough for temperature to affect it's path to equilibrium, the product it is likely to produce as major would be different from the major product of the reaction if I considered the reaction to be too fast for any temperature to affect it's rate or path to equilibrium.

Comment: Remember, her Bromine atom can add to either the tertiary carbon or the secondary carbon atom .

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm not able to follow what you are asking.  I think I need to drop out of this discussion.